# Observe and respond to changes in elements of an array

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm experimenting with Jetpack Compose and am trying to make a Canvas with a number of rectangles, each of which is filled or not depending on the value of a Bool at a corresponding index of an array. When an element of that array changes, the Canvas should redraw.

I've discovered I can't simply make a LiveData array of Booleans, or a list, since for that to work the entire object needs to be recreated each time for setValue to trigger and be observed. So I've made an array of LiveData booleans in a view model;

```
class StripeModel : ViewModel() {
  private val _values = Array<MutableLiveData<Boolean>>(50) { MutableLiveData(false) }
  val values = Array<LiveData<Boolean>>(50) {i->_values[i]}

  fun onValueChanged(index: Int, newVal: Boolean)
  {
    _values[index].value = newVal;
  }
}
```

If I pass that view model to my test function, I can look at a particular member of it in a way that causes the canvas to recompose on change using something like

```
val state by model.values[5].observeAsState();
```

This would be fine if I had a different canvas for each element, but I don't. So I want my single canvas to be looking at all of them, and refresh if any change. The sensible way to do this without explicitly declaring a state variable for each member seemed to be to create an array of states, and the way I came up with to do that was

```
val states = Array<State<Boolean?>>(20){ i->model.values[i].observeAsState()}
```

However, this flags an error because observeAsState needs to be in a function marked @Composable. The outer function itself is, but it seems that's not inherited by the lambda. And if I try and mark the lambda as @Composable then it makes Android Studio very unhappy and tells me to report it as a bug. Doesn't crash the environment but I can't compile it.

The reason I have a strong desire to do this in a single canvas is because I want to be able to click a single item to change its value, or drag across a number of items to change a number of them all at once. That seems like it should be a lot more efficient by handling all the coordinates within one widget rather than having 50 separate widgets and trying to figure out which is at the present location during the drag.

So, how can I make my composable function observe n array elements without explicitly writing n lines that create n variables?

---

Following a few days away I've worked through some of the suggestions people have given.
@cactustictacs suggested the simple approach of making the LiveData array of Booleans. I hadn't actually tried this. Something I'd read made me think it wouldn't work so I tried going more complicated. However, I can't get it to work.

I've simplified the code so it's postable, minus imports.

```
class StripeModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _values = MutableLiveData<Array<Boolean>>(Array<Boolean>(20) {false});
    val values: LiveData<Array<Boolean>> = _values;

    fun onValueChanged(index: Int, newVal: Boolean)
    {
        _values.value?.set(index, newVal);
        _values.value=_values.value;
    }
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val stripeModel by viewModels<StripeModel>();

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Surface{
                MaterialTheme{
                    TestCanvas(stripeModel);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestCanvas(model : StripeModel)
{
    val state by model.values.observeAsState();

    Canvas(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onPress = { it -> model.onValueChanged(5, !state?.get(5)!!) }
                )
            }
            .background(Color.LightGray),


        onDraw={
            val offset = Offset(100f,100f);
            val size = Size(200f,200f);
            if (state?.get(5) == true) {

                drawRect(
                    brush = SolidColor(Color.Blue),
                    size = size,
                    topLeft = offset

                )
            }
            drawRect(
                brush = SolidColor(Color.White),
                size = size,
                topLeft = offset,
                style = Stroke(width = 10f)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

So there's an arbitrary 20 elements of which I'm just looking at index 5. By changing the initialiser I can see that the value is being read on draw. In the debugger I can see that a tap on the screen fires onValueChanged which changes the stored value. However that doesn't cause TestCanvas to recompose.

@chuckj suggested using a mutableStateListOf<MutableState>. If I change my view model to

```
class StripeModel : ViewModel() {

    val values = mutableStateListOf<MutableState<Boolean>>()

    init {
        for (i in 0..20)
        {
            var s = mutableStateOf<Boolean>(false);
            values.add(s);
        }
    }

    fun onValueChanged(index: Int, newVal: Boolean)
    {
        values[index] = mutableStateOf<Boolean>(newVal);
    }
}
```

and I look at it using

```
val state = model.values;
```

the behaviour is the same- no display update on tap.

@Robert Nagy suggested a LiveData<List>. So I created the ViewModel as

```
class StripeModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _values : MutableList<Boolean> = Array<Boolean>(20) {false}.toMutableList();
    val values = mutableStateOf(_values);

    fun onValueChanged(index: Int, newVal: Boolean)
    {
        _values.set(index,newVal);
        values = values; 
    }

}
```

and look at it using

```
val state by model.values;
```

Here, it won't build if I include the line `values = values`. Otherwise, though it builds and runs, it still doesn't cause a recompose.

I've not pasted the whole of the code each time, but it's my understanding that by setting that 'state' value at the start of the composable, any change will trigger a re-run of that function from the start, so only that line is relevant?

So, thanks to those who've commented. Is there something I'm doing wrong that this edit's made apparent?

Comment: You can definitely just call ``setValue`` again with the same object, and have the observers get it - and a single ``LiveData`` with a full state array is how I'd do this too - get the state and redraw the canvas. Are you sure it's not something in the observer logic? Are you calling ``invalidate()`` on the view or something, to make it redraw?

Comment: If you can consider using `mutableStateListOf<MutableState<Boolean>>()`  instead of live data.

Answer (score 0):

`LiveData<List<T>>` Should definitely work.

An example, Screens with lists are commonly modified with:

```
fun removeLastItem(){
    _items.value = _items.value.dropLast(1)
}
```

I suspect something is off at the subscriber/observer.